# Mapping one iterator into another without creating a new type

Tags: function, rust, iterator

I'm trying to see if I can create function that takes one iterator type and transforms it into another, while preserving the functionality that Iterator types like Map have:

```rust
    fn cust_chunk<'a, I>(iter: I, n: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = String>
        where I: Iterator<Item= &'a char>, 
    {
        let res = iter
            .take(n)
            .fold(String::new(), |acc, c| acc + &c.to_string());

        let res = if res == "" {None} else {Some(res)};
        
        res.into_iter()
    }


    #[test]
    fn test_cust_chunk() {
        let td = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];


        // functions as required, but `it` is sampled each time for this to work.
        // it would be better to sample the output iterator instead
        let mut it = td.iter();
        print!("[");
        while let Some(val) = cust_chunk(&mut it, 3).next() {                
            print!("{0}, ", val);
        }
        println!("]");
        // [ABC, DEF, ]


        // only samples the output iterator once, then stops. Can you return an iterator
        // that would sample the input `it` again on .next()?
        // I just wanted to see if I could do this without introducing new types
        let mut it = td.iter();
        print!("[");
        for val in cust_chunk(&mut it, 3) {
            print!("{0}, ", val);
        }
        println!("]");
        // [ABC, ]

        println!("\n---- end stdout ----");
        panic!("stdout")
    }
```

Comment: I don't full understand what you are trying to achieve here, but it looks alot like [`std::slice::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) or if you really need it on iterators [`itertools::Itertools::chunks`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks)

Comment: @Todd I know, but If you do this in a loop you get something quite similar to `chunks`.

Comment: @Cryptjar, how? As I understand, `.take()` consumes the iterator. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Todd, well `.take()` indeed takes `self` by-value, but notice, that a `&mut T`, with `T` being an iterator, is also an iterator in its own right ([see this impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13)). So while `cust_chunk` takes `iter` as an iterator by-value, the while loop passes only a `&mut` as _the iterator value_, therefore the underling iterator (a [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html)) lives on, shorten by 3 entries due to `.take()`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Cryptjar

Answer (score 2):

I think what the OP may be wanting are generators, which Rust does have; but for now that feature is not in the stable releases. The code in a generator would look somewhat similar to what's below.

This is one way to implement something that behaves sort of like a generator. It can be invoked as part of a `for` loop, and the object it returns (an iterator) will hold its state and return the next chunk of items on each successive call to its `.next()` method.

The iterator is automatically generated by the call to `std::iter::from_fn()`. The iterator's `.next()` method invokes the callback.

```rust
fn chunker<I>(chunk_size    : usize, 
              data          : I
             ) -> impl Iterator<Item = impl Iterator<Item = I::Item>>
where I: Iterator + Clone,
      I::Item: Clone,
{
    let mut p = data.peekable();
    
    std::iter::from_fn(
        move || {
            if p.peek().is_some() {
                let c = p.clone();
                for _ in 0..chunk_size { if p.next().is_none() { break; } }
                Some(c.take(chunk_size))
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
}
```

Usage:

```
fn main() 
{
    for chunk in chunker(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].iter()) {
        for n in chunk {
            print!("{}, ", n);
        }
        print!("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
1, 2, 
3, 4, 
5, 6,
```

There's some inefficiency in the algorithm above where the iterator is being cloned to create the `Take` iterators, then the original is being advanced independently.